# Kafka consumer application fails to connect with Azure eventhubs with docker compose but works fine with docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, azure-eventhub

I have a Java application which works fine using docker. It consumes messages from Azure EventHubs, does some transformations and saves them to a database. The dockerfile is simply:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=""
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I have a `deploy.env` file which contains the username, password, server hostname etc. used by the application. All is fine.

I just run the image with this command:

`sudo docker run --env-file deploy.env -d -e --name myapp --rm myregistry.azurecr.io/myapp:latest`

Now I want to put it inside inside a `docker-compose.yml` to run it via `docker compose` together with some other services. It uses exactly the same `deploy.env` file. For now I put it in its own `docker-compose.yml` to make sure there are no conflicts of any sort with other applications.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  myapp:
    image: myregistry.azurecr.io/myapp:latest
    container_name: myapp
    env_file:
      - deploy.env
```

However, when I run it through `docker compose` it fails to connect to Azure EventHubs.
I get this exception (IP addresses and URLs changed for obvious reasons):

```
2023-12-20 20:48:47.805  INFO 1 --- org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-data-processor-1, groupId=data-processor] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-12-20 20:48:47.805  WARN 1 --- org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-data-processor-1, groupId=data-processor] Connection to node -1 (redacted.servicebus.windows.net/52.1.2.3:9093) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.
2023-12-20 20:48:47.805  WARN 1 --- org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-data-processor-1, groupId=data-processor] Bootstrap broker redacted.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-12-20 20:48:47.976  WARN 1 --- o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-data-processor-3, groupId=data-processor] Unexpected error from redacted.servicebus.windows.net/52.1.2.3; closing connection 
java.lang.RuntimeException: non-nullable field authBytes was serialized as null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.read(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:137) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.<init>(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:86) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.SaslAuthenticateResponse.parse(SaslAuthenticateResponse.java:76) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:187) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:109) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:729) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveKafkaResponse(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:576) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:508) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:302) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:181) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:na]
```

It seems that somehow, something is different in the network setup I am getting in `docker compose`.

The error is saying

> This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.

Given that the same exact application is running fine on the same host using plain docker, its not (1) and (3), which seems to point to (2).

Do I need to do some extra configuration in `docker compose` to solve this?

Comment: Do you think it might be relevant to someone trying to help you if you posted the docker and docker compose files you're using?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in them apart from the image being used and inclusion of the .env file. Anyway added them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue is with the particular username Azure Eventhubs uses, which is always `$ConnectionString`.

Now, `docker compose` (not `docker`) interprets this as its own env variable placeholder.

The solution is to escape it with another `$` as follows:
`KAFKA_USERNAME=$$ConnectionString`

Unfortunately, this also means that the env file then won't work with normal `docker` because the username becomes `$$ConnectionString`.

A small hack I found to have the env file work for both `docker` and `docker compose` is to put the following in the `.env` file:

```
ConnectionString=$$ConnectionString
KAFKA_USERNAME=$ConnectionString
```

This way `docker` has the right username directly, while `docker compose` will replace it with the escaped version.